# div inline tag for Addthis code

Tags: html, css, html-table, addthis

I have such a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            My text which consists of three lines.
            Where I write some tips tricks and some news.
            Which is important.
            <div style="display: inline-block" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
                <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
            </div>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

This code puts two buttons to the end of cell, but one of them is in up and other one is down.

If I change to this, buttons are on same line but buttons are put in the beginning of third lines. But I need it to appear in the end of third line. How can I fix this?

```
<div style="display: inline" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
```

**Edit**: this is addthis's script: http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js
It includes this css: http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/counter002.css
Css has following code inside:

```
.addthis_default_style .addthis_counter {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

**Edit2**: I updated to "display: inline; float:right;". Result is this:
[image: result of cell]

Comment: Please add the CSS associated with the classes you include in HTML above. That way we see what behavior the CSS is adding.

Comment: Try to include only the CSS that's being used in the HTML above. If the HTML above is not representative of what you are dealing with in the page, then please update it. You could also provide a link to a url where we can see the working HTML if you like. Otherwise it's very difficult to help you out.

Comment: I just updated the answer to modify the width of the `div` through the  `.addthis_toolbox` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `float:right;` style in the `addthis_toolbox` class.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWxFZ/9/) shows what applying this style accomplishes.

---

**EDIT**

Since you were using the [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) widget I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWxFZ/9/) to use that same widget and added the following CSS style change:

```
.addthis_toolbox {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
}
```